# issue in azure debops deploy file entry unexpectedly large

Tags: azure-devops

i'm getting 
 ##[error]Error: File entry unexpectedly large: 38749 (max: 4096)

when try to deploy using azure web app

[image]

Comment: Is the ZIP file definitely valid and can be extracted? Those `Possibly unsupported ZIP platform type` messages imply something is wrong with the zip

Comment: yes , build was succeed and this happened when try to release

Comment: Hi, does the wiki I shared in my answer can help solve your puzzle? Feel free to let us know your issue progress-)

Comment: not yet still having same issue

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/wiki/Migrating-from-Web-Deploy-to-Run-From-Package-deployment-mechanism):

> But, Web packages created using MSBuild task (with default arguments)
>   has a nested folder structure that can only be deployed correctly by
>   Web Deploy. If Run From Package is used for the above packages, the
>   web package would be copied without honoring the nested folder
>   structure and can cause runtime issues.

For if you want to deploy the package which generated from MSBuild / VSBuild, please try with executing **Archive files** task after **MSBuild / VSBuild** task. So that the file which has a nested folder structure can be deployed with **Web app deploy task** correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So far i solve my problem by downsize the actual project size by deleting old files i think the project should be less then 2GB as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip)

[image]